# Is the Help Center content identical on all sites in the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, help-center

Excluding the Stack Overflow Jobs section on the Stack Overflow website, the main page of the Help Center appears to be identical on all of the non-meta sites I frequent on the Stack Exchange network.  Thus, I am wondering if the content of the Help Center is identical on the different sites.  If not, what is unique?

Edit: I know the Help Center content is different on the Stack Overflow localized sites.

Comment: In non-english sites such [as this one](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) it's localised.

Answer (score 7):

I am aware of only two places that moderators can customize their Help Centers routinely.

I'll use the GIS Help Center as an example because being one of its moderators allows me to screenshot its edit buttons.

The best known is the [On-topic page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which bears the title **What topics can I ask about here?**  The title is the only thing that we cannot change on this page.  If I scroll to its bottom there is an edit button that lets me and the other GIS moderators edit its content.  We do not do that without consulting the GIS Meta community first to ensure there is consensus for what we intend to do.  My recollection is that when we change the content a second moderator has to approve it.  A history of those changes is kept.

[image]

The other place we can edit, which I only noticed very recently, and we have not edited it yet, is on the [front page of the Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help):

[image]

Anything you see above **Find out more about...** has been edited in by a site's moderators.

Answer (score 7):

Some articles are only applicable to specific sites and have been 'manually' added by the Community Managers:

- **How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example** on the Stack Overflow sites: [English](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe more sites in the future
- **How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?** on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising)
- **Enough with the blah blah blah already! I want to build stuff!** on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/help/enough)
- **General Disclaimer** on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) and [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) (and maybe more sites)
- **What is Mi Yodeya? Can I get rabbinic advice here?** on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-mi-yodeya)
- The non-English sites have some Help Center articles for which there seems to be no English equivalent:

  - **Community Values**: [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values) and [Russian Language (in Russian)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/key-values)
  - **Manifest**: [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) and [Russian Language (in Russian)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/manifesto)
  - **Should I translate questions from English to [insert language here]?**: [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english) and [Russian Language (in Russian)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/translate-from-english)
- **Notation** (/help/notation, but with site-specific content):

  - How can I format mathematics here? on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)
  - What notation and symbols are commonly used here? on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)
  - There might be other sites having this page as well.
- [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help) has quite a few site-specific articles:

  - [Can I get legal advice or official government positions here?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/get-legal-advice)
  - [How do I use tags?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/tag-use)
  - [What do I need to do to ask a good question?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/good-question)
  - [What is prior art?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/prior-art)
  - [What is Ask Patents?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/whats-ask-patents)

Also, the order of the articles on the homepage can differ from site to site. Especially the first three pinned articles under "Asking"; compare [Meta Stack Exchange](/help) (left) with [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/) (right):

[image: MSE Help Center]
[image: Astronomy.SE Help Center]

Answer (score 2):

Moderators could edit https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help page.

Our `/help` page is kinda uniq and has link to video about SOru:

> [image]

About help center pages. Moderators could edit some of them (if CM gives us right to edit; AFAIK he can grant permissions for edit only for 3-5 articles simultaneously).

Before editing we usually make collective translation on meta, e.g. article about declined flags: [Перевод статьи из справки «What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8576/15479)